# WebApi dynamic object not binding

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, dynamicobject

I'm trying to send a `dynamic` `object` to an `ApiController`. Setting my breakpoint on the `return null` line, I see that the `parameters` is always `null`.

The `AJAX` call:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function (event) {
    var values = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).toArray();

    var product = {
        Name: $('#name2').val(),
        Price: $('#price2').val(),
        Category: $('#category2').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/filter',
        data: JSON.stringify( product ),
        contentType: 'application/json',

        success: function (data) {
            //alert("succeeded");
        },
        error: function (err, data) {
            alert("Error " + err.responseText);
        }
    });

});
```

The `Controller`:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Products> GetAllProducts(dynamic parameters)
{
    return null;
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I think there needs to be something in the JSON saying that the object you're passing is named `parameters` for the automatic stuff to work how you're expecting.

Comment: Maybe `JSON.stringify( { parameters: product } )` would get you something.

Comment: @TimS. I've tried that too, it's still null.

Comment: In answer to your other question-in-comment below, a `GET` request is not assumed to have a body, only URL parameters, so no binding is attempted on the body.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, what do you mean with 'not assumed to have a body'?

Comment: I meant body data. The definition of a get request is to get a resource specified by a URL. body data is not required as part of a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT :- Changed original answer from a GET to a POST.

Assuming the code you posted is in the FilterController, the GetAll method normally does not take parameters and is used to get all the products. If you want to populate your dynamic there you should change it to a POST like so..

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/filter/GetAllProducts,
        data: JSON.stringify( product ),
        contentType: 'application/json',

        success: function (data) {
            //alert("succeeded");
        },
        error: function (err, data) {
            alert("Error " + err.responseText);
        }
    });
```

then adorn you controller with the HttpPost attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<Products> GetAllProducts(dynamic parameters)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I've tried your option too, it's still null. You're right about GetAll, but this was just a test to get some data in a `dynamic` `object`.

Comment: Hmm... that's weird, the post did work. But why doesn't a GET call work?

Comment: This code is pretty much the same as what we are using.  Put a breakpoint before the ajax call and check JSON.stringify( product ) if you are getting null posted.

Comment: my guess would have to do with the Default Model binder in WebAPI, and the differences between GET having parameters in the url and POST having it as part of the body.. If you want to keep is as a GET, you should look into simply returning an IQueryable and using the oData $filter $where etc operators and making it an oData endpoint

Comment: Do you happen to have a link (to a tutorial or something) about these oData $filter $where etc?

Comment: Here's a link to a post by Julie Lerman from a recent MSDN Magazine. There are also other links from this article. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201742.aspx